# Regex match at least 3 occurences in backslash

Tags: regex

I have following strings I need to differentiate.

```
\\server\path1\path2
\\server\path1
```

First occurrence is always two back slashes `\\` but it may not be beginning of a line. There may be spaces or other text before.

In first string, there should be at least 4 backslashes
`\\`server`\`path1`\`path2......`more backslashes`

In second string, there should only be 3 backslashes
`\\`server`\`path1

I would need 2 regex expressions.

For string 1, I was able to come up with

```
[\\\\]{1}[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+[\\]{1}[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+[\\]
```

Explanation

```
[\\\\]{1}            one occurrence of \\
[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+      any number of one or more alphanumeric with dash (-)
[\\]{1}              one occurrence of \
[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+      any number of one or more alphanumeric with dash (-)
[\\]                 one occurrence of \
```

For string 2, how do I limit number of backslash matches to 3 only.

Comment: Use the same pattern for string1 without the last [\\\] part?
[\\\\\]{1}[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+[\\]{1}[a-zA-Z_\-0-9]+

Comment: I can match but how do I differentiate which string has >=4 and =3 slashes ?

Comment: Try 1) `(?<!\\)\\(?:\\[^\\]+){3}(?!\S)` and 2) `(?<!\\)\\(?:\\[^\\]+){2}(?!\S)`

Comment: Genius! I have to study lookback regexp in detail.

Comment: You should not post others' solutions. Just let the user who suggested a solution know if it works for you and the user will post a full-fledged answer, not a comment.

Comment: ok, I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<!\\)\\(?:\\[^\\]+){3}(?!\S)
(?<!\\)\\(?:\\[^\\]+){2}(?!\S)
```

See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3Ecxc/1) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3Ecxc/2).

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `\` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\\` - a `\` char
- `(?:\\[^\\]+){3}` - three (or 2 as in the second regex) occurrences of a sequence of `\` char and then any 1 or more chars other than `\`
- `(?!\S)` -  a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location (i.e. there must be a whitespace or end of string).